# SSH Pipe File and Execute

Tags: linux, ssh, bash

I am attempting to execute a binary on my ssh server as soon as I log in. However I may want to push the update of my binary with a single ssh login and execute aswell. My current process for do this is

`cat exec | ssh user@host 'cat - > exec; chmod +x exec; ./exec'`

This does not work as when I hit the accutal execution it appears to just freeze. I get no response from the server after this. The strange thing is once I have uploaded the file I can simply execute

`ssh user@host './exec'`

and the file is executed just fine. I know it is reaching the execution process of the binary and the `chmod` is correctly setting the executable bit of the file it just will not execute in a single command. Does anyone have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Use tar instead of cat, and tar preserves mode as well if exec has x bit on.

tar cf - ./exec | ssh user@server 'tar xf -; ./exec'

Comment: No it still doesn't work I have the same problem

Comment: Add a v before f, so -cvf and -xvf as tar options, then verify that ./exec on remote server is executable and same file length by ls -l ./exec, what do you see? I have used the method many times without issues. If still not work possibly your binary is expecting something unexpected.

Comment: No verbose is verifying the file exists after the transfer. LS confirms that the proper permissions are set as well. Executing `ssh user@host './exec'` still results in the expected results after the initial transfer aswell.

Comment: Can you test the process with a system binary such as /bin/ls copied to your own home? That will rule out differences in our system setups.

Comment: It works when I execute /bin/ls. I am at a loss why it won't work for my own binary on the first try, but still work on the second.

Comment: Ah thanks. I am puzzled as well. This makes an interesting problem though. Sorry could not think of anything else at the moment.

Comment: Yeah its strange the problem only occures when I pipe the binary in. If I use wget for instance it is able to execute with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that your binary is stumbling into the ssh escape sequence.  ssh isn't guaranteed to be binary transparent, but you could see if adding '`-e none`' to your ssh command will work.